# How to create android screen (activity) like the Google Play Store v4.9/5.0 (Parallax image+Fading in action bar)

Tags: android, user-interface

I guess the question I've placed explains itself clearly. Tried different solutions available on the internet but getting more than confused.

[image: Something Like this]

First I tried to get the fading effect in action bar [From this tutorial here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/)

But the result was, that the imageview that was placed on the activity screen, along with the action bar, the image too started exhibiting the same properties. Tried to alter, the action bar became fully transparent, and image still continued to exhibit the property.

Any help would be greatly obliged. Thanks

Comment: Well.. what *have* you tried? You claim you've tried "different solutions"... unless you tell us what you've tried, you might just waste our time providing those same solutions to you...

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question, thanks for giving it a glance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look into the Google IO 2014 app which has this effect.
Source code and information on the google dev blog : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/08/material-design-in-2014-google-io-app.html

You can also use library like Parraloid : https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid

Combine it with the tutorial for fading the actionbar and you're good to go.